# Autocomplete Not Working for Jupyter Notebook in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, autocomplete, intellisense, pylance

Autocomplete is not working for jupyter notebook in visual studio code. It used to work, just a day ago. Some time it still work but just for first few seconds of opening the editor and then it just stops showing suggestion and autocompleting the code.

Here are all the settings.json for jupyter:

```
{
    "workbench.editorAssociations": [
        {
            "viewType": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb",
            "filenamePattern": "*.ipynb"
        }
    ],
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python.exe",
    "window.zoomLevel": -1,
    "jupyter.themeMatplotlibPlots": true,
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
        "C:\\Users\\<DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python.exe"
        ],
        "jupyter.variableQueries": [
        
        
        ],
        "terminal.integrated.tabs.enabled": true,
        "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
            "C:\\Users\\<DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python.exe"
        ],
        "jupyter.jupyterServerType": "local",

}
```

here is normal jupyter window:
[Normal Jupyter Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfM0E.png)

here are all the extension installed:
[Extension installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACe9x.png)

Edit:- Autocomplete works well in other languages and strangely it works well before i use any "import statement" in jupyter. before calling "import", it shows me suggestion for "if", "and" and other simple keywords, but once i import numpy or pandas, it even stop showing suggestion for "if","and" or "def"

Answer (score 0):

I kept having a similar problem and fixed it by adding the following line to turn off Jedi autocomplete fixed it (both in vscode and using jupyter notebooks in a browser):

```
%config use_jedi = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Try duplicating the .ipynb file. For me, IntelliSense comes back when I make a new file.

I have conducted some experiments and found that this error happens after I delete some cells.